# How to hide the Join the beta message from my store listing in Google Play?

Tags: android, google-play

So far I've tried pausing the only Open testing track I have and unsyncing all countries. Couldn't find any information on the topic in the official documentation. Does anyone know how to do it?

Many thanks for your time.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

it is possible that you are the only one seeing `Join Beta Program` message because you are internal tester as well.

Try from another phone that your 100% sure that is not added as an internal tester, and you will see that the message does not appear on that phone.

Comment: Thanks for answering! I've seen the message in many phones now, not only mine.

Answer (score 0):

Two weeks after pausing the Open testing track and unsyncing all countries the message is not there anymore, so, if anyone is having the same issue I'd advise to do the same. Thanks and good luck with your apps!